# Access ADODB - Procedure or function has too many arguments specified

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, adodb

I have recently started using ADODB to execute stored procedures and I have run into a bit of a hitch. Whenever I try and run this certain stored procedure it is giving me the error: `Run-time error '-2147217900 (80040e14)': [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Procedure or function CheckTeamMember has too many arguments specified.` However, when I double check both the call in vba and the SP in sql server they both have the same number of arguments, 3.

Here is the SP:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[CheckTeamMember] (
    @projectID VARCHAR(45),
    @empID INT,
    @exists BIT OUTPUT
)
AS
    DECLARE @trueFalse BIT;

    SET @trueFalse = 0

    IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 projectteammember_id FROM ci_projectteammember 
                    INNER JOIN ci_projectteam ON ci_projectteammember.projectteammember_team = ci_projectteam.projectteam_id 
                    WHERE ci_projectteam.projectteam_project = @projectID AND projectteammember_member = @empID)
    BEGIN
        SET @trueFalse = 1
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @trueFalse = 0
    END

    SELECT @exists = @trueFalse
```

Here is the code in vba (this is a class module. I run init() before running the actual query function):

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private conDB As adodb.Connection
Private cmdCheckTeamMember As adodb.Command

Public Sub init(con As String)
    Set conDB = New adodb.Connection
    conDB.ConnectionString = con
    conDB.Open

    Set cmdCheckTeamMember = New adodb.Command

    With cmdCheckTeamMember
        .ActiveConnection = conDB
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        .CommandText = "CheckTeamMember"
        .Prepared = True
    End With

End Sub

Public Function checkTeamMember(projectID As String, empID As Integer) As Boolean

    Dim exists As Boolean

    With cmdCheckTeamMember
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@projectID", adVarChar, adParamInput, 45, projectID)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@empID", adInteger, adParamInput, , empID)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@exists", adBoolean, adParamInputOutput, , exists)
        .Execute
    End With

    checkTeamMember = exists

End Function
```

Comment: That looks like it should work, double check you are connected to the correct database (or rename the SP & see what happens).  You can use the SQL Profiler tool to trace the exact calls that are being made to the server.  Note that `checkTeamMember = exists` assumes the `exists` variable is updated with the output value - this is not the case, to read it you need to ask the Paramaters collection for the value: `exists = cmdCheckTeamMember.Parameters("@exists").Value`

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, I had completely forgotten about the server profiler. From the looks of what I saw (and understand) I was setting the output arg to a actual value which was causing it to error out. @AlexK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to re-use a Command, you need to add the parameters only once.  So add the parameters in `Init`, and only access the parameters in `ckdCheckTeammember`.  Something like:

```
Public Function checkTeamMember(projectID As String, empID As Integer) As Boolean

    Dim exists As Boolean

    With cmdCheckTeamMember
        .Parameters("@projectID").value = projectID
        .Parameters("@empID").value = empID

        .Execute

        exists = .Parameters("@exists").value 
    End With

    checkTeamMember = exists

End Function
```

Comment: This works, thank you. From my understanding of what was changed this works because 1. my old code was trying to provide a output argument with a value and 2. each time I would run it it would add more parameters. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes.  You were adding parameters each time and not retrieving the value of the output parameter after `.Execute`.